# Floating a block of text between 2 paragraphs

Tags: css, css-float

I want to float a formatted block of text so it is positioned to flow with the first and second paragraphs of text in the document.

I want the block to float in such a way where the first 2-3 sentences of paragraph 1 wrap around the top and left sides of the floated box.

Plus, I want the block to float in such a way that it causes paragraph 2 to wrap around the left and bottom sides of the floated box.

I understand everything is relevant to the amount of content in paragraphs 1 and 2 along with the floated box.

I know how to float the box with paragraph 1 or paragraph 2 but I want to be able to position the float such that both paragraphs wrap around the float box.

Has anyone done that before?

Comment: It's almost as though you need to float it with a "phantom" top-margin or a transparent top-margin. I'm thinking there is some sort of neat css trick to do this...hoping someone has done it before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you upload a picture of what you are trying to accomplish? I got lost with all the words xD

Comment: A picture would be of great help. Didn't quite get you.

Comment: Yeah, thought of that while typing...pictures do paint thousands of words -- http://bit.ly/uIaQou

Comment: Again, I can handle all the formatting...it's just the positioning of the floated container I need assistance with. Thanks

Comment: P.S. I did try styling the floated container with a negative top-margin and placing the container between the 1st and 2nd paragraphs in the document flow. But what ended up happening (at least in FF) was the floated container overlaid the text in paragraph 1 such that both blocks of text were appearing on top of each other. I'm thinking that CSS is not up to the task yet. Hope to be wrong.

Comment: @utopicam - uploaded http://bit.ly/uIaQou -- thanks for looking.

Comment: @sasidhar - uploaded http://bit.ly/uIaQou -- thanks for looking.

Comment: @Dr.DOT is the formatted text, that floats to the right with a background an image?? or is it also a piece of text??

Comment: @sasidhar -- "piece of text" ... I need to to be index-able by the SE bots which is why I am trying to format it as a floated container. Thanks for looping back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help http://jsfiddle.net/uusTK/ ??
**If splitting the text is ok:**
http://jsfiddle.net/GymnK/1/

Comment: @Dr. DOT sasidhar's fiddle is the way to go. BUT, to make the text wrap around the box, you have to put that span in the middle of the text you want to divide. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uusTK/2/ Does that work for you?

Comment: @Dr.DOT so that(utopicam's comment) is your intended result?? While you don't want to split your text right??

Comment: Thanks @sasidhar ... "utopicam" tweak to the framework you laid out is absolutely the solution I was looking for. Thanks for the really neat CSS !!

Comment: I can't help wondering now about that phantom magic css trick! I'm sure there are lots of options to do this in a more "profficient" way. I'll look into it :D @sasidhar yep, it's not the best option, specially if you have dynamic text. But if you have a static page, with content that will not change too much...

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the meaning of the word **wrap**??? Wrapping should be done whenever possible, but not in a predefined and static manner?? And the position of the formatted box seems to be static and fixed in that location. Is this the right solution?? I am not satisfied..??

Comment: Maybe I jumped the gun. I didn't look that close at your span id #1 content. My planned use is not to randomly insert span #2 inside the flow of existing paragraph #1. I plan to have `<p id="1">lorem...</p>` then `<span class="float_this_right">Ipsum...</span>` followed by `<p id="3">Dolor...</p>`. I would like to set a static top margin on the floated container such that either 2 or 3 sentences always appear above any floated box. Then, regardless of how many paragraphs follow, I just want the remaining part of the document to flow. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I plan to tinker with your "flow concept" and your "css" later this afternoon. If I come up with a CSS that consistently does what I am attempting, I'll post back. Thanks!